# C++ Подключение SDL Библиотеки к Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, фреймворк, sdl

Здравствуйте, перейду сразу к делу. Решил написать небольшой фреймворк для "текстовухи", но на определенном этапе понял что SDL библиотека попросту не подключена. Попытался наладить по гайдам в Сети, но так ничего и не вышло из этой затеи. В Visual Studio 2017 просто напросто нет тех вкладок, которые мне нужны.
Делал по этом гайду: 
https://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-SDL-with-Visual-Studio-2017

http://prntscr.com/j6be17 Как вы можете заметить на этом скрине, все сделано строго по инструкции но нарушается 4 Раздел 2 часть.

Comment: Это потому что вы открыли страницу свойств конкретного .cpp файла, а не проекта. И выкладывайте скриншоты на встроенный хостинг.

Comment: Спасибо большое. В будущем буду пользоваться местным хостингом.