# Проблема с SDL на Visual Studio 2017. Идентификаторы SDL_SetVideoMode и тд. не определяются

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl

[image: Пример проблемы]

Из-за этой ошибки не могу скомпилировать проект. Собственно, SDL устанавливал по этому гайду: https://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-SDL-with-Visual-Studio-2017

Даже второй раз все перепроверил, все стоит так как по гайду.

```
`#include "Project.h"

 class MyScreen : public Screen
{
private:
Input * input;

 public:
void Start()
{
    input = game->GetInput();

    SDL_WM_SetCaption(" () ", 0);
    MessageBox(0, " () ", " () ", MB_OK);
}
void Update()
{
    if (input->IsKeyDown('w') || input->IsExit())
        game->Exit();
}
 };

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
Game game;
return game.Execute(new MyScreen(), 500, 350);
}
```

`

```
#include "Graphics.h"
#include "SDL.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

 Graphics::Graphics(int width, int height)
{
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
Screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
 }

 Image* Graphics::NewImage(char* file)
{
Image* image = new Image();
image->surf = SDL_DisplayFormat(SDL_LoadBMP(file));

return image;
 }

 Image* Graphics::NewImage(char* file, int r, int g, int b)
{
Image* image = new Image();
image->surf = SDL_DisplayFormat(SDL_LoadBMP(file));

SDL_SetColorKey(image->surf, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY | SDL_RLEACCEL,
    SDL_MapRGB(image->surf->format, r, g, b));

return image;
 }

 bool Graphics::DrawImage(Image* img, int x, int y)
{
if (Screen == NULL || img->surf == NULL)
    return false;

SDL_Rect Area;
Area.x = x;
Area.y = y;

SDL_BlitSurface(img->surf, NULL, Screen, &Area);

return true;
 }

 bool Graphics::DrawImage(Image* img, int x, int y, int startX, int startY, 
 int 
endX, int endY)
{
if (Screen == NULL || img->surf == NULL)
    return false;

SDL_Rect Area;
Area.x = x;
Area.y = y;

SDL_Rect SrcArea;
SrcArea.x = startX;
SrcArea.y = startY;
SrcArea.w = endX;
SrcArea.h = endY;

SDL_BlitSurface(img->surf, &SrcArea, Screen, &Area);

return true;
}

void Graphics::Flip()
{
SDL_Flip(Screen);
SDL_FillRect(Screen, NULL, 0x000000);
}




/*
  Simple DirectMedia Layer
  Copyright (C) 1997-2018 Sam Lantinga <slouken@libsdl.org>

  This software is provided 'as-is', without any express or implied
  warranty.  In no event will the authors be held liable for any damages
  arising from the use of this software.

  Permission is granted to anyone to use this software for any purpose,
  including commercial applications, and to alter it and redistribute it
  freely, subject to the following restrictions:

  1. The origin of this software must not be misrepresented; you must not
     claim that you wrote the original software. If you use this software
     in a product, an acknowledgment in the product documentation would be
     appreciated but is not required.
  2. Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such, and must not be
     misrepresented as being the original software.
  3. This notice may not be removed or altered from any source distribution.
      */

      /**
       *  \file SDL.h
       *
       *  Main include header for the SDL library
       */


      #ifndef SDL_h_
      #define SDL_h_

      #include "SDL_main.h"
      #include "SDL_stdinc.h"
      #include "SDL_assert.h"
      #include "SDL_atomic.h"
      #include "SDL_audio.h"
      #include "SDL_clipboard.h"
      #include "SDL_cpuinfo.h"
      #include "SDL_endian.h"
      #include "SDL_error.h"
      #include "SDL_events.h"
      #include "SDL_filesystem.h"
      #include "SDL_gamecontroller.h"
    #include "SDL_haptic.h"
    #include "SDL_hints.h"
    #include "SDL_joystick.h"
    #include "SDL_loadso.h"
    #include "SDL_log.h"
    #include "SDL_messagebox.h"
    #include "SDL_mutex.h"
    #include "SDL_power.h"
    #include "SDL_render.h"
    #include "SDL_rwops.h"
    #include "SDL_shape.h"
    #include "SDL_system.h"
    #include "SDL_thread.h"
    #include "SDL_timer.h"
    #include "SDL_version.h"
    #include "SDL_video.h"

    #include "begin_code.h"
    /* Set up for C function definitions, even when using C++ */
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif

    /* As of version 0.5, SDL is loaded dynamically into the application */

    /**
    *  \name SDL_INIT_*
    *
    *  These are the flags which may be passed to SDL_Init().  You should
     *  specify the subsystems which you will be using in your application.
     */
    /* @{ */
    #define SDL_INIT_TIMER          0x00000001u
     #define SDL_INIT_AUDIO          0x00000010u
    #define SDL_INIT_VIDEO          0x00000020u  /**< SDL_INIT_VIDEO implies 
    SDL_INIT_EVENTS */
    #define SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK       0x00000200u  /**< SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK implies 
    SDL_INIT_EVENTS */
    #define SDL_INIT_HAPTIC         0x00001000u
    #define SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER 0x00002000u  /**< SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER                               
    implies SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK */
    #define SDL_INIT_EVENTS         0x00004000u
      #define SDL_INIT_NOPARACHUTE    0x00100000u  /**< compatibility; this flag       
    is 
    ignored. */
      #define SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ( \
                SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_INIT_VIDEO |                                                 
     SDL_INIT_EVENTS | \
                SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK | SDL_INIT_HAPTIC | SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER \
            )
      /* @} */

      /**
       *  This function initializes  the subsystems specified by \c flags
       */
      extern DECLSPEC int SDLCALL SDL_Init(Uint32 flags);

      /**
       *  This function initializes specific SDL subsystems
       *
       *  Subsystem initialization is ref-counted, you must call
       *  SDL_QuitSubSystem() for each SDL_InitSubSystem() to correctly
       *  shutdown a subsystem manually (or call SDL_Quit() to force shutdown).
       *  If a subsystem is already loaded then this call will
       *  increase the ref-count and return.
       */
      extern DECLSPEC int SDLCALL SDL_InitSubSystem(Uint32 flags);

      /**
       *  This function cleans up specific SDL subsystems
       */
      extern DECLSPEC void SDLCALL SDL_QuitSubSystem(Uint32 flags);

      /**
       *  This function returns a mask of the specified subsystems which have
       *  previously been initialized.
       *
       *  If \c flags is 0, it returns a mask of all initialized subsystems.
       */
      extern DECLSPEC Uint32 SDLCALL SDL_WasInit(Uint32 flags);

      /**
       *  This function cleans up all initialized subsystems. You should
       *  call it upon all exit conditions.
       */
      extern DECLSPEC void SDLCALL SDL_Quit(void);

      /* Ends C function definitions when using C++ */
      #ifdef __cplusplus
      }
      #endif
      #include "close_code.h"

      #endif /* SDL_h_ */

     /* vi: set ts=4 sw=4 expandtab: */
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [C++ Подключение SDL Библиотеки к Visual Studio 2017](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/815340/c-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-sdl-%d0%91%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: Это мой первый вопрос о том, как подключить библиотеку, у меня теперь проблема с самими идентификаторами.

Comment: Эта проблема говорит о том, что библиотеку вы так и не подключили... А вообще вместо рандомного скриншота следует привести скриншот настроек проекта, текст компилируемого файла и лог сборки.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Aw0q7kA

Comment: А теперь еще добавьте минимальный пример кода.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/IBkSam1 Надеюсь хватит. Могу еще поскидывать

Comment: Только код и лог надо следует добавлять текстом и все вместе стоит добавить в сам вопрос...

Comment: Обновил, проверяйте. Если понадобится больше - пишите. Там просто у меня их уже больше 10 файлов, все не перекопирую.

Comment: А у вас случаем не продолжается ли проблема из прошлого вопроса, когда разные настройки у проекта и у файла?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/dkwIvXy Нет, настройки вроде как идентичны.

Comment: А вот если поставить курсор название файла в `#include "SDL.h"` в graphics.cpp и нажать F12 - куда вы попадаете? У вас там случаем нет одноименного файла `SDL.h`?

Comment: Ничего не происходит по нажатию F12

Comment: А если `Ctrl + Shift + G`?

Comment: Обновил, вот что написало. Создался новый SDL.h файл

Comment: Ну значит заголовочный файл находится нормально и проблема с чем-то еще. Создайте лучше новый проект и попробуйте постепенно переносить в него функционал чтобы локализовать проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Не ту версию библиотеки подключаете.

`SDL_SetVideoMode` - это из SDL 1.2, его нет в SDL 2.0.